# What is the equivalent of bootstrap spacing breakpoints in Material-UI?

Tags: material-ui

In Bootstrap I can control the spacing with screen-size dependent classes like so:

```
{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}
```

e.g. `.p-sm-2 .p-xl-4` will set the padding on the small screen to 2 units and on a large screen to 4 units.

How would I achieve the same in Material-UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Box` component.

```
<Box p={{ xs: 2, lg: 4 }}>
</Box>
```